# Memory leaks in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following memory leaks in my code. What does it mean? How can I fix this?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    **int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);**
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no leak here, it's just the boiler plate code. What makes you think you leak? What does instrument say? Static analyzer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is from your main.m file. It seems odd that this part of your code would leak, if at all??

How did you find this leak?

Are you using the simulator or a real device?

If using the simulator you can sometimes have leaks that are not leaks at all, it is always better to test these kinds of things on a real device (which you have not specified). Double check all of your release, retains etc in your code. You might just spot something you have not released. (in xcode 4 use the assistant editor I find it better to spot these kinds of things alt+cmd+enter).

Your question otherwise is hard to answer, you might want to edit it with how you found it and in what environment.

Hope some of this helps

[EDIT] saw you tagged this with cocos2D (what version are you using of that?) there are some reported issues elsewhere on SO with memory leaks using older versions of cocos2D

Comment: @Alexander Do you have any about Apple Leaks relaxation in Iphone/Ipod Apps.mean how much bytes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what you are saying here. Not sure if iOS5 is under NDA??? but I have read some where on the internet that in iOS5 some of the memory management will be done for you (I can not confirm this as I always do it myself). If this is what you mean by relaxation then I guess this answers your question. 

I want to help you out but I don't really understand what you want.

[EDIT] by doing it for you I mean the compiler does it for you